# Ability to read Apple Time Capsule Hard Drive on OS X?

Tags: macos, time-capsule

Is there a way to read hard drive from Apple TimeCapsule on my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Time Capsule is merely an Airport Extreme with built-in hard drive. The Airport {express|extreme}-devices support disks support all hard drives which are formatted using a compatible file system (FAT16/32, HFS+).

Mac OS X supports all these file systems, too. You will be able to connect your hard drive to your mac eg. using USB - maybe you will need to get some [S-ATA to USB-Adaptor](http://www.google.com/?q=sata%20to%20usb) for connecting it.